# Spring WebClient partial update with @PATCH method when calling another microservice

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, express, spring-webclient

I have Node.js and Java services where I am trying to use the PATCH method and update the single item in the request body. When I am sending the below request body directly to the Node.js service(`http://localhost:8004/products/xxx`) it just updates the size and the rest of the items did not change.

```
{
    "size": 42,
}
```

But when I hit my Java service(`http://localhost:8005/products/xxx`) which calls the Node.js service it updates the size but the rest of the items are set to null like below. What I am doing wrong?

```
Updated product {
  title: null,
  desc: null,
  img: null,
  categories: null,
  size: '42',
  price: null
}
```

Java

```
public Mono<Products> updateProduct(String id, Products editProduct){
    return  webClient
            .patch()
            .uri("/products/{id}", id)
            .body(Mono.just(editProduct), Products.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Products.class);
}

@PatchMapping("/products/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public Mono<Products> updateProduct(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Validated @RequestBody Products editProduct){
    return  basketService.updateProduct(id, editProduct);
}
```

Node.js

```
    router.patch('/:id', async (req, res) => {
      try{
        const productId = req.params.id
        const updates = req.body
    
        console.log("Updated product", updates)
    
        const result = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, updates)
        res.status(200).json(result);
      
      }catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
})
```

Comment: what is the content of `updates`?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara when I make a PATCH request from Java its like below.
`title: null,
  desc: null,
  img: null,
  categories: null,
  size: '42',
  price: null
}
`

Comment: only update `size` in the `findByIdAndUpdate`.

Comment: Yeah, but what I will do if I want to update the price or any other items? What confused me, why it worked with Nodejs and when I hit Java it set null rest of the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can annotate your `Products` class to let Jackson know that it should not serialize `null` values:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Products {

 //...
}
```

You can also do that with [a configuration property in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper) globally, but this would affect also JSON payloads server by your application.

Comment: Thanks, @Brian, it works as expected. But why should I need to add this annotation? Its a kind of annotation that I always need to add my models in spring ?

Comment: This annotation tells the JSON serialization process that it should ignore `null` values. This is a specific configuration that should not be applied generally. In your case, you might encounter issues if you need to `null` out a field - with this option, your client cannot send any `null` value.